# PUB/SUB in Rails using ActionCable & Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, actioncable

In my controller#action, I would like to perform_async 2-3 jobs & subscribe to those jobs(using ActionCable). And once those jobs were completed, then my controller#action will return the proper response.

In each job will do publish once completed using ActionCable.

I have seen the Sidekiq PRO > Batch which might handle this but I would like to know if this can be achieved with the process or flow I have sited.

Reason doing this is to avoid THREADING, but need those jobs to run almost in parallel.

Thanks!

Comment: "then my controller#action will return the proper response." How? The controller action schedules the jobs and then it finishes and needs to return a response. It makes more sense if the jobs themselves get a handle on the ActionCable and broadcast a response

Comment: Hi Joel, that's another thing, I would like to know if I can do subscribe and wait on controller#action. I understand your point but this is a different use case for reasonable reason atleast on our case.

Users accessing the endpoint(controller#action) has no knowledge about PUB/SUB, all they know is if they send a request to our endpoint, they should receive a response. So it's more of PUB/SUB will be implemented internally.